# Promise that is resolved with debug

Tags: angularjs, debugging, routes, promise

I am in an angular project.

What is happening is that I have a promise in the resolve of a route that isn't resolved but if I am debugging the application the promise is resolved.

Someone with some theory about what is happening?

Comment: I think you will have to provide some code snippets, jsfiddle, plunker, gist

Comment: You have a race condition.